# python exponential function - incorrect exponential values

Tags: python, math, numpy, exponential

I have a range of negative values : -30 to -80
Let's say

```
array_values = [-30, -31, -32, -33, -34, -35, -36, -37, -38, -39, -40, -41, -42, -43, -44, -45, -46, -47, -48, -49, -50, -51, -52, -53, -54, -55, -56, -57, -58, -59, -60, -61, -62, -63, -64, -65, -66, -67, -68, -69, -70, -71, -72, -73, -74, -75, -76, -77, -78, -79, -80]
```

I'm evaluating this expression : `|(-k).exp(array_values[idx]/k)|` `for idx in array_values`

```
k=35
```

The problem I'm having is that, there's no smooth exponential curve I'm getting after plotting this expression.

So I thought I'd check with just `exp(array_values[idx]/k)` 
Here are a bunch of values I get from the calculator and python(both math.exp() and numpy.exp() respectively)

```
exp(-30/35): Calculator: 0.42437284567   Python:0.36787944117144233
exp(-31/35):             0.4124194827           0.36787944117144233                 
exp(-32/35):             0.40080281159          0.36787944117144233
exp(-33/35):             0.38951334871          0.36787944117144233
exp(-34/35):             0.38754187754          0.36787944117144233
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug in the function?
My code line for this is

```
expos = [math.exp(-i/35) for i in array_values]
```

Comment: Convert your list elements to `floats`. Dividing `int` with `int` gives you `int`!

Comment: or add `from __future__ import division` at the top of your script.

Comment: Yes, I was on a brain freeze or something looks like. Such an idiot. Thanks @igavriil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting your values to positive by putting a minus in front of an already negative value. You should also divide it to 35.0 so that it returns a `float` instead of an `int`. This works:

```
import math
array_values = [-30, -31, -32, -33, -34, -35, -36]
expos = [math.exp(i/35.0) for i in array_values]
print expos
```

result:

```
[0.42437284567695, 0.4124194827001579, 0.40080281159210923, 0.3895133487108618, 0.37854187754140095, 0.36787944117144233, 0.35751733497916927]
```

Comment: I feel like an enormous idiot right now for this rookie mistake! 
of course divide it by float! 
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing `int` with `int` results in `int`. So

```
array_values = [-30, -31, -32, -33, -34]
test = [-i/35 for i in array_values]
>>> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
expos = [math.exp(-i/35) for i in array_values]
>>> [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

If you convert one of the numbers in the division to `float` will produce the expected results.

```
test = [float(-i)/35 for i in array_values]
>>> [0.8571428571428571, 0.8857142857142857, 0.9142857142857143, 0.9428571428571428, 0.9714285714285714]

expos = [math.exp(-float(i)/35) for i in array_values]
#or expos = [math.exp(-i/35.0) for i in array_values]
>>> [2.3564184423836605, 2.4247157128777834, 2.494992477791509, 2.5673061098152665, 2.6417156445012626]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can check, `0.36787944117144233` is just `e^(-1)`, and you can infer that you are passing the floor of the fractional arguments (because you are performing an integer division).

Nose-on-your-face bugs of such a kind in fundamental functions are highly unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
expos = [math.exp(float(-i)/35) for i in array_values]
```

The integer division returns integer values for example:

```
>>> 1/2
0
```

but a float value:

```
>>> 1.0/2
0.5
```